# Prevent header hyphenation in tabulary

Tags: tables, hyphenation, tabulary

How is it possible to prevent `tabulary` environment hyphenating table headers?

Perhaps redefining `\tyformat`, but I can't find any reference to this command.

### EDIT

As suggested in comments, I tried with: `\newcolumntype{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}J}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{YYYYY} 
      \hline
     & label 1 with much more text than is needed & label 2 is also very long & label 3 & label 4 \\ 
      \hline
    1 & item 1 & item 2 & item 3 & item 4 but again with too much text \\ 
      2 & A & B & C & D \\ 
       \hline
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately The fourth column gets hyphenated, while I'd like only line breaks. I don't see differences with an ordinary `{JJJJJ}` in place of the custom column type.

Comment: as in anywhere else in latex `\mbox{my heading}` if you want to prevent linebreaking altogether, or `\raggedright` (or `\centering`) will prevent hyphenation unless the word is wider than the box or add `\hypenpenalty=10000` to prevent hyphenation even then

Comment: In general I'd like line-breaking without hyphenation. Anyway, wrapping a table header in `\mbox` causes it to overlap the following one. As for `\raggedright`, I tried 
`\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}J}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{YYYY} ...`
 
and hyphenation persists.

Comment: If you get hyphenation in raggedright the word is longer than the column? As I said you can also set hyphenpenalty, but then it will be overful and overprint as for mbox. This is why you should always include a complete small document in your question that shows the problem. If you edit your question to have such an example, it will be much easier to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `\raggedright` then latex will only hyphenate if the word is longer than the line width, so you just need to make sure that you don't get ridiculously small columns. I set `tymin` as 1cm here. Note you don't need to define `Y` for ragged right columns as `tabulary` pre-defines `L` for essentially the same thing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}

    \setlength\tymin{1cm}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LLLLL} 
      \hline
     & label 1 with much more text than is needed & label 2 is also very long & label 3 & label 4 \\ 
      \hline
    1 & item 1 & item 2 & item 3 & item 4 but again with too much text \\ 
      2 & A & B & C & D \\ 
       \hline
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```